# Segmentation fault when opening file in C?

Tags: c, arrays, file, fault

I'm very new to programming and I'm trying to write code that reads "numbers.tsv4" (.tsv4 means tab separated values, 4 to a line) and puts the numbers into an array. Right now I'm just focusing on counting the amount of numbers in a file, so I can initialize the array size.

```
    int main(void)
{
 int cur;
 FILE* spData;
 int size=1;

 spData = fopen("numbers.tsv4", "r");                                    

 while ((cur = fgetc(spData)) != EOF) {
    if ((cur = fgetc(spData)) == '\t') {
    size++;}
 }
 fclose(spData);
 printf("%d", size);
 return;
}
```

I keep getting a segmentation fault and I've changed so many things to try to figure it out. Could someone give me a hand? Thanks!

Comment: The most likely reason for your segfault is that "numbers.tsv4" does not exist, fopen returns NULL, your code fails to check it, and fgetc(NULL) blows up. P.S. Otherwise, the overall logic is completely broken anyway. It will fail to count half of the tab characters in the file, on average.

Comment: Have you debugged it to figure out exactly what happens before the segfault?

Answer (score 0):

The structure with your while statement is the problem. At the beginning of each iteration, you are already getting the next character with `fgetc()` and assigning it to `cur`. Then inside the loop, in the `if(...)` statement, you discard the `cur` by calling a new `fgetc()` and assigning the result to `cur`. So, change it in the following way:

```
while ((cur = fgetc(spData)) != EOF) {
    if (cur == '\t') {
    size++;}
}
```

You see, when you try to invoke the `fgetc()` twice (both in `while(...)` and `if(...)`), you probably get the `EOF` in the `if(...)` statement. Then in the next iteration with the `while(...)` statement, you try to access somewhere out of file, which gives you the segmentation fault.